# Windows task scheduler not triggering a task on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, vbscript

I have a task that is supposed to run a script I made, every 10 minutes, but it just doesn't seem to trigger it.

In the task scheduler it says that next run time is in 10 minutes, but when the time comes, nothing happens.

I have multiple triggers just because I was hoping at least one of them might work:

- One time. At 0.00 - After triggered run every 10 minutes.
- At log on of any user - After triggered run every 10 minutes.
- On idle - After triggered run every 10 minutes.

Since "next run time" appears, you would think the triggers are working...
Nothing happens though.

And yes, I am sure the script itself works.
It's a vbscript, which I thought should work with the scheduler, but just in case, I made a batch to run the script and put the batch under the scheduled trigger, but neither way worked.

Any idea what's wrong?

EDIT: I now use a small program called system scheduler. My script is running fine with that and I don't imagine it uses much resources so I can just keep using that.

It would still be useful to figure out what's wrong with the windows task scheduler though, so answers are still appreciated.

Comment: Please show the syntax on how you're calling the vbscript.

Comment: What do you mean? In the batch? I just used `cscript "D:\Dropbox\My programs\ip.vbs"`. Besides, like I said, I have tested the script and the batch. They both work. The task scheduler just doesn't run them. If you mean the task, [here](http://gyazo.com/38ae86f6164cb2a38897b76d84403919)

Answer (score 0):

Under start a program, you would point to cscript and not to the vbs itself.

`C:\Windows\System32\Cscript.exe`

Then add arguments:

`D:\Dropbox\My programs\ip.vbs`

Comment: Didn't think of that... Shouldn't it still work trough a batch though? Either way, I just tried what you said and it didn't work either. I don't get what I'm doing wrong, but oh well... The system scheduler program I'm now using is working just fine and seem light enough.

Comment: A bit late to this, but did you place the argument text between quotes? `"D:\Dropbox\My programs\ip.vbs"`. Reason being is that the space will break.

Answer (score 0):

Tthe Windows 10 Scheduled Tasks utility is full of bugs.  See https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/idle-task-scheduler-powershell

Particularly problematic are idle triggers.  You might try the same task without the idle trigger.  (Also, use the feedback app to get MS to fix the task scheduler.)