# Task scheduler issues on Windows 10. Same task configuration works on Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Basically tasks won't launch when supposed to by daily or login repetition triggers.
They can also be launched manually and launch once on user login, but repetitions are postponed each time they should run, without any indication that they were attempted to run on tasks history (it is enabled).

I'm using the great [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper library](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com) for C#, though how I create the task appears to have no impact.

I've found out that the same task configuration that works perfectly under Windows 7 and 8, on x86/x64 and different languages, is failing on Windows 10.

I've tested on 2 different virtual machines, using different Windows 10 installation files and I have the same strange behavior on both.

There are no conditions I can see that would prevent them to be run (such as being on battery or only on idle). Plus, like I mentioned the exact same program is able to create scheduled tasks which execute flawlessly on previous Windows version.
I even exported the task in XML format from a Windows 7 x64, imported it into a clean Windows 10 VM and it has the same issue.

I'm pasting the XML export of the task below.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-06-02T16:32:22.334-08:00</Date>
    <Description>Test</Description>
    <URI>\TestTask</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT15M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2016-06-02T16:32:22.334-08:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT15M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT1M</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2302200855-1744179440-2378765128-1002</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Users\user\Downloads\TestTask.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: BTW, I found this post that appears to have the same issue. No solution there either: http://superuser.com/questions/985919/windows-task-scheduler-not-triggering-a-task-on-windows-10